# How to fix wrongly linked mono lib in buildroot image?

Tags: mono, buildroot

With the current buildroot 2015.11.1 configured to use mono, the libMonoPosixHelper.so will be searched in the /home/userX/buildroot/output/host/usr/lib/ path. This path and file may exist on my building machine, but not on the target.

I have a working workaround with creating this folder and copy libMonoPosixHelper.so from /usr/lib at startup in the ram disk.

The following search results for libMonoPosixHelper are from

```
buildroot/output/build/
```

Where is the right place to start searching the error?

> find /home/userX/buildroot -name "*.in"|grep mono|awk '{print "grep -H libMonoPosixHelper " $1}'|sh

```
host-mono-4.0.2.5/runtime/Makefile.in:  sed 's,target="$(prefix)/$(reloc_libdir)/libMonoPosixHelper$(libsuffix)",target="'$$d'/libMonoPosixHelper.la",' ../data/config > $@t
host-mono-4.0.2.5/support/Makefile.in:libMonoPosixHelper_la_DEPENDENCIES = $(am__DEPENDENCIES_2) \
host-mono-4.0.2.5/support/Makefile.in:am__libMonoPosixHelper_la_SOURCES_DIST = errno.c map.c map.h mph.h \
host-mono-4.0.2.5/support/Makefile.in:am_libMonoPosixHelper_la_OBJECTS = $(am__objects_3) $(am__objects_5) \
host-mono-4.0.2.5/support/Makefile.in:libMonoPosixHelper_la_OBJECTS = $(am_libMonoPosixHelper_la_OBJECTS)
host-mono-4.0.2.5/support/Makefile.in:libMonoPosixHelper_la_LINK = $(LIBTOOL) $(AM_V_lt) --tag=CC \
host-mono-4.0.2.5/support/Makefile.in:  $(AM_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(libMonoPosixHelper_la_LDFLAGS) \
host-mono-4.0.2.5/support/Makefile.in:SOURCES = $(libMonoPosixHelper_la_SOURCES) \
host-mono-4.0.2.5/support/Makefile.in:DIST_SOURCES = $(am__libMonoPosixHelper_la_SOURCES_DIST) \
host-mono-4.0.2.5/support/Makefile.in:  libMonoPosixHelper.la           \
host-mono-4.0.2.5/support/Makefile.in:libMonoPosixHelper_la_SOURCES = \
host-mono-4.0.2.5/support/Makefile.in:libMonoPosixHelper_la_LIBADD = \
host-mono-4.0.2.5/support/Makefile.in:# libMonoPosixHelper_la_LDFLAGS = -no-undefined -version-info 1:0:1
host-mono-4.0.2.5/support/Makefile.in:libMonoPosixHelper_la_LDFLAGS = -no-undefined -avoid-version
host-mono-4.0.2.5/support/Makefile.in:libMonoPosixHelper.la: $(libMonoPosixHelper_la_OBJECTS) $(libMonoPosixHelper_la_DEPENDENCIES) $(EXTRA_libMonoPosixHelper_la_DEPENDENCIES) 
host-mono-4.0.2.5/support/Makefile.in:  $(AM_V_CCLD)$(libMonoPosixHelper_la_LINK) -rpath $(libdir) $(libMonoPosixHelper_la_OBJECTS) $(libMonoPosixHelper_la_LIBADD) $(LIBS)
host-mono-4.0.2.5/data/config.in:   <dllmap dll="MonoPosixHelper" target="@prefix@/@reloc_libdir@/libMonoPosixHelper@libsuffix@" os="!windows" />
host-mono-4.0.2.5/mono-core.spec.in:rm -f %buildroot%_libdir/libMonoPosixHelper.a
host-mono-4.0.2.5/mono-core.spec.in:%_libdir/libMonoPosixHelper.so*
mono-4.0.2.5/runtime/Makefile.in:   sed 's,target="$(prefix)/$(reloc_libdir)/libMonoPosixHelper$(libsuffix)",target="'$$d'/libMonoPosixHelper.la",' ../data/config > $@t
mono-4.0.2.5/support/Makefile.in:libMonoPosixHelper_la_DEPENDENCIES = $(am__DEPENDENCIES_2) \
mono-4.0.2.5/support/Makefile.in:am__libMonoPosixHelper_la_SOURCES_DIST = errno.c map.c map.h mph.h \
mono-4.0.2.5/support/Makefile.in:am_libMonoPosixHelper_la_OBJECTS = $(am__objects_3) $(am__objects_5) \
mono-4.0.2.5/support/Makefile.in:libMonoPosixHelper_la_OBJECTS = $(am_libMonoPosixHelper_la_OBJECTS)
mono-4.0.2.5/support/Makefile.in:libMonoPosixHelper_la_LINK = $(LIBTOOL) $(AM_V_lt) --tag=CC \
mono-4.0.2.5/support/Makefile.in:   $(AM_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(libMonoPosixHelper_la_LDFLAGS) \
mono-4.0.2.5/support/Makefile.in:SOURCES = $(libMonoPosixHelper_la_SOURCES) \
mono-4.0.2.5/support/Makefile.in:DIST_SOURCES = $(am__libMonoPosixHelper_la_SOURCES_DIST) \
mono-4.0.2.5/support/Makefile.in:   libMonoPosixHelper.la           \
mono-4.0.2.5/support/Makefile.in:libMonoPosixHelper_la_SOURCES = \
mono-4.0.2.5/support/Makefile.in:libMonoPosixHelper_la_LIBADD = \
mono-4.0.2.5/support/Makefile.in:# libMonoPosixHelper_la_LDFLAGS = -no-undefined -version-info 1:0:1
mono-4.0.2.5/support/Makefile.in:libMonoPosixHelper_la_LDFLAGS = -no-undefined -avoid-version
mono-4.0.2.5/support/Makefile.in:libMonoPosixHelper.la: $(libMonoPosixHelper_la_OBJECTS) $(libMonoPosixHelper_la_DEPENDENCIES) $(EXTRA_libMonoPosixHelper_la_DEPENDENCIES) 
mono-4.0.2.5/support/Makefile.in:   $(AM_V_CCLD)$(libMonoPosixHelper_la_LINK) -rpath $(libdir) $(libMonoPosixHelper_la_OBJECTS) $(libMonoPosixHelper_la_LIBADD) $(LIBS)
mono-4.0.2.5/data/config.in:    <dllmap dll="MonoPosixHelper" target="@prefix@/@reloc_libdir@/libMonoPosixHelper@libsuffix@" os="!windows" />
mono-4.0.2.5/mono-core.spec.in:rm -f %buildroot%_libdir/libMonoPosixHelper.a
mono-4.0.2.5/mono-core.spec.in:%_libdir/libMonoPosixHelper.so*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted the bug to [buildroot bugzilla](https://bugs.busybox.net/show_bug.cgi?id=8651). 
It got patched and newer versions of buildroot >2016 don't show the problem when a mono executable is started using a SerialPort.